# Creating ViewController to only run first time the application is run iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am working on an application and I want to implement a tutorial that would run the firs time the application is run on the Phone. I have already setup NSUserDefaults and can successfully determine and flag the application once it is run for the first time. My problem now is moving from the Tutorial View Controller to the main view controller.

My current set up has the main view controller set as the root controller to my app and my tutorial view controller needs to be shown and then dismissed only the first time the app is run.

What's the best method for implementing it? I was thinking of showing it as a Modal view and have the main view controller show it if it detects the first run. Any suggestions?

Note that I am not using Storyboards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with your approach of presenting a modal on top of your root view controller when you detect first launch.

Use `presentViewController:animated:completion:` to display it, with animated: set to NO. That way it will appear on top of the root view controller and cover it. Then when you're done with the first view controller you can dismiss it and reveal your root view controller underneath.

Comment: I have a followup question if you don't mind. I am currently detecting the FirstLaunch in ViewDidLoad, this is where I access the UserDefaults and then set an integer Object in my class as 1 or 0 accordingly. Then in my ViewWillAppear I am creating the If condition that checks this integer, i built it like this to avoid having to access the UserDefaults everytime the viewwillappear is called. What do you think about this approach? And do you think there is a better location to check for FirstLaunch?

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, choose your root view controller programmatically.  Something like:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if ([self isFirstLaunch])
    {
        self.window.rootViewController = [TutorialViewController new];
        [self setFirstLaunch NO];
    }
    else
    {
        self.window.rootViewController = [MyRegularRootViewController new]
    }
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Or possibly as a child of the rootViewController and have it manage the tutorial.

Comment: I was going to go with a similar implementation however I was confused as how to switch back to the RegularView Controller once the tutorial is finished.

Comment: That usually causes more problems than it solves. The view controller hierarchy ends up being different on first run than on subsequent runs. And, you can't get rid of the "one-off" first view controller once you're done with it. It persists for the entire first run of the app, taking up memory, even though it will never be used again. Much better to display the "one-off" VC on top of the normal root view, then dismiss it once you're done with it.